# Removing Filter item isotop Jupiter theme

Tags: wordpress, portfolio, jquery-isotope

How can I remove the first item "All" from the isotope filtering in my Jupiter theme?

Here is what I'm talking about: 
https://demos.artbees.net/jupiter/portfolio/portfolio-grid-full-width/

Is there any CSS fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want CSS fix here it is.

```
.portfolio-grid .mk-grid ul li:first-child{
     display:none;
}
```

paste this in style.css or any other .css file which is being called on this page.

you can remove this from code as well but for that you need to dig into isotop file thats bit difficult if you are not familiar with theme files.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try JS code:

```
(function($){
 var portfolio_all= jQuery('#mk-filter-portfolio ul li');
 jQuery(portfolio_all[0]).hide();
 function change_active_por(){
   var portfolio_header = jQuery('#mk-filter-portfolio ul li a');
  portfolio_header[1].click();
 }
 setTimeout(change_active_por,2000);

})(jQuery);
```

As far as I know Jupiter has some section to put custom JS code. Check it.